# Wordpress, can't update post_name

Tags: wordpress

According to the docs, my code below should work:

```
$my_post = array(
  'ID'           => 12345,
  'post_title'   => 'This is the new post title.',
  'post_name'    => 'and-this-the-new-name',
);

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

But it does not work entirely; the *title* does change unlike the *name*.

I've deactivated all plugins so as to be sure nothing foreign is possibly affecting what I'm doing.

I'm running the most current version of WordPress.

Could it be because I've created the post with a status as `pending`?

According to others, I should set status at creation of the *post* to `publish`.

But I can't afford to do that as I need to set the `post_name` **before** the *post* is published.

What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I cross checked:

Insert post with status=publish -> post_name is set automatically.

then did the following:

```
$update_args =  array (
  'ID'        => 12345,
  'post_status' => 'pending',
  'post_name' => 'try-again-my-own-name',
);
wp_update_post($update_args );
```

Result: Status is set to pending **but** post_name is now empty.

Comment: its working fine. where you using this code?

Comment: In my own functions.php. I think it's because the posts are pending. You can't insert/change a post_name until status is set to publish.

Comment: no. you can update if posts are pending.

Comment: I think it could be because the author I am using has no admin rights.

Comment: yes. it may be the issue.

Comment: no, it's not. I created the post with author=1 (wich is the admin). Did not work.

Comment: But who's calling your code? What function/hook is executing it?

Comment: When is this code getting executed?

Answer (score 0):

wp_update_post() is a wrapper for wp_insert_post().

If you take a look at the [**reference here**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), you'll see why it's clearing out your post_name:

```
// Don't allow contributors to set the post slug for pending review posts.
if ( 'pending' == $post_status && !current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
    $post_name = '';
}
```

Comment: But user CAN publish. Thanks for the hint. I think I have to go deeper.